# How to connect a native React App to a Rest API using fetch when the Rest API url is http://localhost:8080/

Tags: reactjs, rest, fetch

I need to connect my Rest API project, which was created using Eclipse, with the React project, which was created using WebStorm. My Rest API url is http://localhost:8080/TrnReserve/rest/trains. When I run this, I only see a blank web page. When I use a url like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users, it works perfectly and displays the fetched data.

I tried replacing localhost with the IP4 address of the system and many other solutions such as proxies. None works with this. Can someone help me with this?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { data: [] };

}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:8080/TrnReserve/rest/trains`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => this.setState({ data: json }));
}


render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {this.state.data.map(trains => (
                    <li>
                        {trains.trainNo}: {trains.trainName}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
```

[image]

Comment: I would catch the errors. .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)); also check the response.text() to see if JSON method is unable to parse.

Comment: You're coming up with an empty page because your API is returning XML and not JSON and there is an error parsing the response as JSON. Does your API serve a JSON response?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with the XML response. I tried a lot to change it to a Json response with my program, but the Json response is not sent to the web page.